# NVIDIA GT 610 and Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, lubuntu, xorg

I've been trying to get an old GT 610 I have lying around working with an older machine running Lubuntu 18.04. I installed the recommended driver version through the Software & Updates (version 390). Then I tried rebooting the system with the monitor connected to the HDMI output of the graphics card, and the screen was blank and the GUI woudn't start up; I would have to switch the HDMI to the integrated graphics and hit `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` to get the Ubuntu prompt and then restart the GUI using `sudo telinit 5`. But when I boot up with the HDMI connected to the integrated graphics, everything works as it did without the graphics card.

`nvidia-smi` and `lshw -c display` both work and show the graphics card

Running the NVIDIA X Server config just how a blank dialog window, and trying to run it through the command `nvidia-settings` gives me the error:

```
** Message: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling it (using `apt purge *nvidia*`), no changes.
I even tried installing it from the .run file found on the NVIDIA website
However, I did notice that the version number for `nvidia-settings` was ahead of the driver version I installed (440 vs 390), but I couldn't find an `nvidia-settings` package that matched the version number.

`sudo prime-select nvidia` tells me the NVIDIA profile is already selected

there's no NVIDIA blacklist file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` or `/lib/modprobe.d/`, and I did add a nouveau blacklist file

SecureBoot isn't even supported by my computer

Oh, and I should probably mention that I shouldn't upgrade Lubuntu because I need a certain software version that Lubuntu 20.04 doesn't have

Comment: I'm catching up on older Lubuntu support requests. First, have you resolved your issue? Second, is there any real need for the proprietary drivers? It's an old card and not very performant. The opensource driver is adequate (for many) unless you're intending to game with it. Maybe trying to use the Nouveau drivers will get you better results?

Comment: @KGIII No, I haven't resolved this. I guess I could try the open-source drivers. I'm basically just trying to see if it would work; maybe do some AI training with it

Comment: I'm mostly just checking because you're listed on an unanswered support section of the Lubuntu site - I'm currently a *tester*, meaning I break things in repeatable ways. I'm not actually sure how to help, but I'm pretty much all you've got. I can start a bounty for you, if you'd like. Your older card probably isn't going to do much in the way of AI training, as it's 8 years old at present - but that shouldn't dissuade you. It's just that Nvidia support for older cards isn't all that great. It's better than AMD, but still not great.